# .htaccess - Redirect Subdirectory to Same Subdirectory of another domain

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

This is quite simple. I need help redirecting the following. I need to redirect a subdirectory from website a to the same to website b. I need this on a wildcard subdirectory, meaning that if I visit any subdirectory, it will redirect me to the same subdirectory but on another domain. Example below.

Request URL:

```
https://exampleA.com/random
```

Redirect URL:

```
https://exampleB.com/random
```

This should work on ALL subdirectories of exampleA.com. Not just one.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: yes I did try something

Comment: Post your attempt in your question to get an answer.

Comment: Well, it obviously didnt work.

Comment: Yes we know it didn't work that's why you have posted a question. But if show your failed attempt then it would be easier for folks to understand what's not working and help you further.